# How to initialize a web application in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I was using WebSphere Application Server, and it gives a platform initialization listener which is invoked when an app gets started. Now, I am using Apache Tomcat, but have not found such stuff, and what I'm trying to do is do some initialization work before the application begins to serve requests.

How should I do it by Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Are you using any framework, such as SpringMVC, Struts 2, or PlayFramework? If so, there may be framework specific answers that are more natural than the `ServletContextListener`. But if this is simply a Java/Servlet app, the given answer is the way to do it.

Comment: No, I'm not using any.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a `Listener` class what implement `ServletContextListener` like this:

```
package com.vy;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class StartStopListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Servlet has been started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Servlet has been stopped.");
    }

}
```

Add configuration information to `WEB-INF\web.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.vy.StartStopListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

When run Tomcat, You will see result at console screen:

```
Servlet has been started.
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: There is no need for configuration in web.xml when using @WebListener annotation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ServletContextListener` API. Please read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). You can go and checkout this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)

You should write custom application start-up code in this method

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("ServletContextListener started");   
}
```

Note : There will not be any issues while moving to another servers, if needed in future.